# Как сделать так, чтобы бот телеграм отправлял значение переменной только мне

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет. У меня есть генератор кода:

```
                payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range (15)) #генерируем сам код, который состоит из 15 символов
                print (payid) #пока оставлю для отладки
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вот твоя ссылка на оплату: [ссылка позже].\nОбязательно в комментариях к оплате укажи этот код: ')
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, payid)
```

хочу, чтобы бот отправлял сам код не только пользователю, а еще и мне.
Пример:
"Пользователь first_name сгенерировал вот такой payid: {payid}

Comment: Бот как-то должен знать что вы это вы. Сохраните свой `chat.id` в переменную и потом ее используйте в `send_message`.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Как я понял, надо после генерации кода добавить примерно так: bot.send_message(мой ид, 'мой текст')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, надо после генерации кода добавить примерно так:

```
bot.send_message(мой ид, 'мой текст')
```

Работает.